# FileNotFoundError ,while Django - AWS S3 image file resizing

Tags: django

The Django website have media files on AWS S3, when Admin upload new image, model layer supposed to resize image and save.

MODELS.PY

```
class News(models.Model):
   
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='newsimage')
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img1 = Image.open(self.photo.name)
        if img1.height > 400 or img1.width > 400:
            output_size = (845,440)
            img1.thumbnail(output_size)
            img1.save(self.photo.name)      

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Newsdetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

The code work fine when media stored in local storage. If the same in S3 , it makes error.

However if I dont resize image and save directly , it works fine with AWS S3, THE BELOW CODE GIVE NO ERROR AND WORKS FINE AS ITS NOT RESIZING IMAGE

```
class News(models.Model):
   
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='newsimage')
    #DELETED IMAGE RESIZING 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Newsdetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Error page - as attached image.

[image]

Comment: It seems more like an AWS permissions issue than a Django issue. Have you checked if your django application has write permissions in your AWS bucket?

Comment: yeah, without image resizing it uploads successfully

Comment: Do you have logging enabled in your S3 bucket? If not, enable it and post the errors here that you might find in there.

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace? Also check if you have the static files configured properly. Since you are running the application on AWS, I'm assuming the server is running in production mode (debug = false)?

Comment: Thank you , I will look into it